# assign references

Tags: python

Is there a way to assign references in python?

For example, in php i can do this:

```
$a = 10;
$b = &$a;
$a = 20;

echo $a." ".$b; // 20, 20
```

how can i do same thing in python?

Comment: Out of interest, why?  What do you use this for?

Comment: Did cru3l ask how to write good programs or how to do something in particular? In Python, this style of programming may be inappropriate or impossible, but it does not matter why he wants to use references. He is asking the question, and it does not involving solving his broader problem.

Comment: @Noctis: if we'd all just solve posited problems, this site wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Noctis Skytower: "Did cru3l ask how to write good programs"  Actually.  Yes, they did ask how to write a good program.  They've started down the wrong path, reached a dead-end, and asked for help.  They need the **right** solution, not some uselessly sophisticated work-around that doesn't solve their real problem

Comment: Thanks for helping my understanding. It reminds me to watch out for presumptuous people who infer unverified problems and try to solve them.

Comment: @Noctis Skytower: He is asking the wrong question, and the question as sked does not involving solving his broader problem.  We can continue down to the dead-end.  Or we can suggest a better approach.  I can see the value in focused, literal, legalistic reading of bad questions coupled with technically spot-on answers that don't help any in the long run.

Comment: @Noctis Skytower: I wasn't saying anything about whether this was a good or bad thing to do.  I was only curious as to what you would use it for.

Comment: @neil: If you wanted to write a function or method that did not return variables but still changed the value of a variable somewhere else, passing mutable variables (or by reference) may be helpful. For example, you have a button in tkinter and bind a command to it: `flag = [False]; button['command'] = FlipBool(flag)`. The FlipBool class may be defined as: `class FlipBool: def __init__(self, flag): self.flag = flag; def __call__(self): self.flag[0] = not self.flag[0]`. If the flag were passed by reference instead of boxed in a list, the flag would not have to be unboxed each time it was used.

Comment: @niel: (continued) The previous contrived example could be written differently if variables were not passed by reference, were mutable, copies of them were made on assignment, and passing references were optional. It will never happen as it goes against the language's design, but if it did, the example could be written as (pending syntax decisions): `flag = False; button['command'] = FlipBool(@flag)`. The FlipBool class would also be written differently: `class FlipBool: def __init__(self, flag): self.flag = @flag; def __call__(self): self.flag = not self.flag`. "@" means "do not make a copy."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In python, if you're doing this with non-primitive types, it acts exactly like you want: assigning is done using references. That's why, when you run the following:

```
>>> a = {'key' : 'value'}
>>> b = a
>>> b['key'] = 'new-value'
>>> print a['key']
```

you get `'new-value'`.
Strictly saying, if you do the following:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = a
>>> print id(a) == id(b)
```

you'll get True.

**But!** Because of primitive types are immutable, you cant change the value of variable `b` itself. You are just able create a new variable with a new value, based on `b`. For example, if you do the following:

```
>>> print id(b)
>>> b = b + 1
>>> print id(b)
```

you'll get two different values.

This means that Python created a new variable, computed its value basing on b's value and then gave this new variable the name `b`. This concerns all of the immutable types. Connecting two previous examples together:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = a
>>> print id(a)==id(b)
True
>>> b += 1
>>> print id(b)==id(a)
False
```

So, when you assign in Python, you always assign reference. But some types cannot be changed, so when you do some changes, you actually create a new variable with another reference.

Comment: [Be careful](http://gist.github.com/784475) with object identity of immutable objects in Python.  It might not be what you expect.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Thanks for that example. But after a = 257 \n b = a expression always gives a is b == True, am I right?

Comment: there is no such thing as primitive types in python.

Comment: yeah, I know. I just thought, that this Java-like terminology would make things easier to understand.

Comment: Using this Java-like terminology is at best confusing. A Java programmer might think `1` is a primitive in Python too.

Comment: @ikostia So what are you referring to when you say "primitive types"?

Answer (score 2):

In Python, everything is by default a reference. So when you do something like:

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=x
x[1]=-1
print y
```

It prints [1,-1,3].

The reason this does not work when you do

```
x=1
y=x
x=-1
print y
```

is that `int`s are *immutable*. They cannot be changed. Think about it, does a number really ever change? When you assign a new value to `x`, you are *assigning a new value* - not changing the old one. So y still points to the old one. Other immutable types (e.g. strings and tuples) behave in the same way.

Comment: The reason is *nothing* to do with the fact that ints are immutable. In the second example you are rebinding x to -1, y remains bound to 1.